# Does TLD effect SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains

We are looking at buying a domain and all `.com` options are gone. I was thinking to get something like `<businessname>.store` but i was wondering if `.store` would effect SEO of the website? is it better or is it bad? Or does it even matter now a days.

I am not sure if i am using correct terminology for `TLD` so i couldn't find an answer when i was trying to google. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer? No. Slightly longer answer? Except that .store is not what people will think of first. Any .com site will retain "top of mind" presence over .store. There are always domain names available to you - you just have not thought of a good/acceptable one yet. Do not be tied to the business name too much. Use the domain name to signal what the site is about. Be patient. You will find one. I promise! Cheers!!